# Python: algorithm deos not works

Tags: python, django

I want to extract data of django.po file (internationalization) in xls (to discuss with non IT project manager)

so first, I want to code a function that will extract lines of django.po in a list of tuples
(don't know if it is the easiest way but...)

and after, I will use xlwt export data in xls files (each tuple will be written in a line)

**translation.txt**

```
#: .\myproject\settings.py:1
#: .\myproject\settings.py:2
msgid "English"
msgstr "Anglais"

#: .\myproject\settings.py:3
msgid "French"
msgstr "Français"
```

**expected result** : liste of 2 tuples

```
[
('#: .\myproject\settings.py:1','#: .\myproject\settings.py:2','msgid "English"','msgstr "Anglais"'),
('#: .\myproject\settings.py:3','msgid "French"','msgstr "Français"'),
]
```

**current result** : second tuple missing

```
[
'(#: .\myproject\settings.py:1','#: .\myproject\settings.py:2','msgid "English"','msgstr "Anglais"')
]
```

**function**

```
def translation():
    fichier_traduction = r"C:\Users\translation.txt"
    file = open(fichier_traduction, newline='', encoding='utf-8')
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    liste = []
    tuple = ()
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) > 0:
            tuple = tuple + (row[0],)
        else:
            liste.append(tuple)
            tuple = ()
    return liste
```

Comment: Your expected result is not valid Python. Please correct!

Comment: From the csv.reader documentation `Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings.`, i.e. You basically get your desired format:
`for row in reader: liste.append(tuple(row))`.

Comment: In my example, I want that the first 4 lines of traduction.txt insert in a tuple, and after the empty line, add another tuple with the next 3 lines...

Comment: I found my error: i need an empty line at the end of my file